# Django redirect from other domain gives Page Not Found error

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api, referrer

When clicking on a url that points to my Django website, I get a Page Not Found error. When I look to the error with DEBUG=True, I see that the "current path" displayed in the error message is different from the actual url.

For example, take a look at the shared articles on linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/company/huvepharma-nv/. When clicking on the first post I am redirected to my Django website: https://huvepharma.com/news/article/how-butyrate-producing-bacteria-can-support-food-safety/. This gives me a Page Not Found error, saying that the current path is **company/huvepharma-nv/**, which is the path on the LinkedIn website.

[image]

How can I fix this?

I added the following fix in the past but now I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with DEBUG=False. So the quick fix is also not working anymore.

```
def handler404(request, exception, template_name='errorhandlers/handler404.html', *args, **kwargs):
    if request.META.get('HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE') == 'cross-site':
        return redirect(request.path)

    response = render_to_response(template_name)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

Apache2 configuration:

**Port 80:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin frederik@adbuddy.be
        ServerName huvepharma.com
        ServerAlias www.huvepharma.com

        ErrorLog "||/usr/bin/rotatelogs /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/logs/error/error-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
        CustomLog "||/usr/bin/rotatelogs /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/logs/access/access-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" combined

        Alias /static /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/static
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/media
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        #WSGIDaemonProcess huvepharma.com python-home=/home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/venv python-path=/home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma
        #WSGIProcessGroup huvepharma.com
        #WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/huvepharma/wsgi.py process-group=huvepharma.com

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/huvepharma>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =huvepharma.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.huvepharma.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Port 443:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin frederik@adbuddy.be
        ServerName huvepharma.com
        ServerAlias www.huvepharma.com

        ErrorLog "||/usr/bin/rotatelogs /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/logs/error/error-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
        CustomLog "||/usr/bin/rotatelogs /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/logs/access/access-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" combined

        Alias /static /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/static
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/media
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess huvepharma.com python-home=/home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/venv python-path=/home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma
        WSGIProcessGroup huvepharma.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/huvepharma/wsgi.py process-group=huvepharma.com

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/websites/huvepharma/huvepharma>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/huvepharma.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/huvepharma.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you use apache / nginx or something like that? If so, can you please check the access log and see what is the requested URL. Let me know the request URL

Comment: Never mind. It seems like the configuration of the webserver you are using is the problem, not sure though. When I create a hyperlink to your site with the http version of your page `"<a href="http://huvepharma.com/news/article/how-butyrate-producing-bacteria-can-support-food-safety">Test</a>"` it works. But when I give the https version, it shows the 404 error. Just double check the part where you handle that. I guess I will need more information about your set up.

Comment: I have added my apache configurations. I have set up ssl with `sudo certbot --apache -d huvepharma.com -d www.huvepharma.com`.

Comment: This is what my access log says:
`94.226.234.86 - - [11/Jun/2020:06:41:32 +0000] "GET /news/article/how-butyrate-producing-bacteria-can-support-food-safety/ HTTP/1.1" 302 503 "https://www.linkedin.com/company/huvepharma-nv/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Can you do a https hyper link and http hyperlink to that same article and post the access logs for both?

Comment: HTTPS
`94.226.234.86 - - [16/Jun/2020:06:07:41 +0000] "GET /news/article/use-of-fibre-degrading-enzymes-for-a-healthier-poultry-gut/ HTTP/1.1" 302 3792 "https://www.linkedin.com/company/huvepharma-nv/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: HTTP
`94.226.234.86 - - [16/Jun/2020:06:09:33 +0000] "GET /news/article/use-of-fibre-degrading-enzymes-for-a-healthier-poultry-gut/ HTTP/1.1" 301 715 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"`